# update values in dict in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have values as mentioned below for more than 2000 users in my mongodb.

User -1 :

```
myClocks_s" : "[{"clockId":"2","clockLabel":"Tambaram","hasClock":true},{"clockId":"12","clockLabel":"Park town","hasClock":true}]"
```

User -2 :

```
myClocks_s":"[{\"clockId\":\"5.5\",\"clockLabel\":\"Chennai,IN\",\"hasClock\":true},{\"clockId\":\"2\",\"clockLabel\":\"Tambaram\",\"hasClock\":true}]"
```

I would like to change the clockid for all the locations. The new clockid for chennai will be 6 instead of 5.5 , the new clock id for tambaram will be 1 instead of 2 and so on . How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Is this essentially a one-shot conversion or is it run over and over in production?  I suspect the former, in which case the easiest thing to do (esp. with only 2000 users) is to write a little script that reads every doc, walks the `myClocks_s` array and updates values based on the `clockLabel` field, then calls `update()` to push the `myClocks_s` array back into the DB.   Will run in about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Runs in about 1.3 seconds for 2000 entries in a collection.

```
var newClockIds = {
    "Chennai":6,
    "Tambaram":1
}

db.foo.find().forEach(function(d) {
    var didSomething = false;
    d['myClocks_s'].forEach(function(item) {
        w = newClockIds[item['clockLabel']];
        if(undefined != w) {
            item['clockId'] = w;
            didSomething = true;
        }
    });
    if(didSomething) {
        // Update key/criteria  is the incoming _id for the doc which is unique.
        rc = db.foo.update({_id:d['_id']}, {$set: {"myClocks_s": d['myClocks_s']}});
        // Ensure success                                                                              
        if(rc['nMatched'] != 1 && rc['nModified'] != 1) {
            print("? could not update id", _id);
        }
    }
});
```